# How can I create a DIV that's located in the center of my browser screen?

Tags: html, css

I tried the following:

```
<body style="height: 100%;">
    <div style="display: block; height: 30rem; width: 100rem; margin: auto;">
    x
    </div>
</body>
```

What happens that is the box is centered with the correct right and left margins. But there seems to be no margins at the top and bottom. Note 1rem is equal to about 10px so there should be plenty of space at the top and bottom. However the DIV just sits at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that:

```
#yourdiv {
    position:fixed;

    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; 
    margin-left: -15em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried like this?

```
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    <div style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;">
    x
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css instead of your inline css part

```
#mydiv {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:100em;
    height:30em;
    margin-top: -9em; 
    margin-left: -15em; 
}
```

eg:-

```
<body style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="mydiv">
    x
    </div>
</body>
```

FYI:- position:fixed; does the trick here. it will keep your div in the center even if you scrolled down the page.
Hope this helps

Comment: Can you tell me why your suggesting -9 and -15 for the margin top and left ?

Comment: ah just ignore them.I copied this answer from the site i'am currently working at and i forgot to delete them. those 2 lines are totally useless for this particular job.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ZETwK/)**</kbd>

I have used `%` for sizing, its complete responsive, try changing width and height in `px`, still div remains completely center of the page.

HTML

```
<div class="divX">x</div>
```

css

```
.divX {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    height: 30%;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: DivX :D
Oh the memories :)